# mongodb query to find the min price in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My documents:

```
[{
"title": "lenovo x-100",
"brand": "lenovo",
"category": "laptops",
"variant": [{
    "price": 30000,
    "RAM": "4GB",
    "storage": "256GB",
    "screen": "full hd",
    "chip": "i3"
}, {
    "price": 35000,
    "RAM": "8GB",
    "storage": "512GB",
    "screen": "full hd",
    "chip": "i5"
}, {
    "price": 40000,
    "RAM": "12GB",
    "storage": "2TB",
    "screen": "uhd",
    "chip": "i7"
}],
"salesCount": 32,
"buysCount": 35,
"viewsCount": 60
},
{
"title": "samsung12",
"brand": "lenovo",
"category": "mobile phones",
"variant": [{
    "price": 11000,
    "RAM": "4GB",
    "ROM": "32GB"
}, {
    "price": 16000,
    "RAM": "6GB",
    "ROM": "64GB"
}, {
    "price": 21000,
    "RAM": "8GB",
    "ROM": "128GB"
}],
"salesCount": 48,
"buysCount": 39,
"viewsCount": 74
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
 _id:"lenovo",
 minPrice:1100
}
```

I have tried this method of aggregation

```
[{
$match: {
    brand: 'lenovo'
}
}, {
 $group: {
    _id: '$brand',
    prices: {
        $min: '$variant.price'
    }
}
}, {
$unwind: {
    path: '$prices'
}
}, {
$group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    minPrice: {
        $min: '$prices'
    }
}
}]
```

I want to find the minimum price based on the brand, this query is returning the expected output but is there any better way to get the expected outcome because using $unwind operator in quite expensive in the sense it may take longer execution time, hoping for positive response.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to unwind before the first grouping (and remove the following unwind and hrouping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` to replace the second `$group` stage.

1. `$match`
2. `$group` - Push `variant.price` into new array and results nested array of array.
3. `$project`:

   3.1. `$reduce` - Use to flatten the nested array from the result *2* by `$concat` the arrays into one.

   3.2. `$min` - Select min value from the result *3.1*.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      brand: "lenovo"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$brand",
      prices: {
        $push: "$variant.price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      minPrice: {
        $min: {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$prices",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOXiMAfgIkn)